# long converter JSON.parse form MongoDB

Tags: java, json, mongodb, long-integer

could you help me with conver long values  from **MondoDB**,

here is piece of code:

> DBObject workCircleDbObject = (DBObject)
>   JSON.parse(source.get("workcircle").toString());

`source.get("workcircle")` returns: `java.lang.Long value`;
but after, `JSON.parse(source.get("workcircle").toString());`  returns

```
java.lang.Integer;
```

so `workCircleDbObject` contains integer values, not long.

How can I save long values not integer in java?

Thank you

Comment: correction `.toString()` returns a string instead of Integer

Comment: BUT  com.mongodb.util.JSON contains:: public static java.lang.Object parse(java.lang.String s)

Comment: Yes, and it does so. It parses `source.get("workcircle").toString()` and obviously this returns a string literal of a value <= Integer.MAX_VALUE and not denoted with "L" to mark it as a long representation.